# Unable to use userns remap in Docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Docker seems to have some issues with LXC in Ubuntu 16.04. I removed LXC according to this gist: https://gist.github.com/estesp/e37b06e51384fa0ad6067af42a693925

However now I get

```
$ docker run --rm busybox date
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: rootfs_linux.go:42: preparing rootfs caused "permission denied".
```

I'm not sure where to go from here to be able to use the `userns-remap` feature.

For reference here's my `docker.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --userns-remap=Default --graph /media/externaldrive/docker
MountFlags=slave
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=0
# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently a bug. As stated from the docker member Phil Estes "estesp", the following was [said](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/24834#issuecomment-240836035):

> that is a permission bug because of more limited permissions/access to
>   an existing directory in the provided path to --graph

This is now filed as a bug at the docker github issue tracker:

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25847

as stated on commit https://github.com/estesp/docker/blob/43a1df6be2fa0c76b521680bbd5dc84db2cfd898/daemon/daemon_unix.go#L1018

The graph directory needs `o+x` permissions for docker to work. After I used `chmod o+x` on the directory I was able to use userns remap.